# Lua - Download file asynchronously via HTTP

Tags: asynchronous, lua, io

I just finish reading `copas` core code. And I want to write code to download file from website asynchronously, but copas seems to only support socket IO.

Since Lua does not provide async syntax, and other packages will surely have their own event loop that, I think, can not run along side copas' loop.

So to async download file via http, do I have to find a package that suppprt async http and async file IO at the same time? Or any other ideas?

Comment: I just realized `step` function that resumes each task in copas is actually exported, so it's possible to use this `step` function, a data queue, a bunch of async file writers as consumer to make an async downloader.

Answer (score 0):

After reading bunches of code, I can finally answer my own question.

As I mention in my comment to the question, one can make use of the step function exported by async IO library, and merge multiple stepping into a bigger loop.

In the case of `luv`, it uses external thread pool in C to manage file IO, and use a single-threaded loop to call pending callbacks and manage IO polling (polling is not needed in my use case).

One can simply call file operation function provided by `luv` to make async file IO. But still need to step `luv`'s loop to call callbacks bind to IO operations.

The integerated main loop looks goes like this:

```lua
local function main_loop()
    copas.running = true
    while not copas.finished() or uv.loop_alive() do
        if not copas.finished() then
            copas.step()
        end
        if uv.loop_alive() then
            uv.run("nowait")
        end
    end
end
```

`copas.step()` is the stepping function of `copas`. And `uv.run("nowait")` make `luv` run just one pass of event loop and don't block if there is no ready IO when polling.

A working solution looks like this:

```lua
local copas = require "copas"
local http = require "copas.http"
local uv = require "luv"

local urls = {
    "http://example.com",
    "http://example.com"
}

local function main_loop()
    copas.running = true
    while not copas.finished() or uv.loop_alive() do
        if not copas.finished() then
            copas.step()
        end
        if uv.loop_alive() then
            uv.run("nowait")
        end
    end
end

local function write_file(file_path, data)
    -- ** call to luv async file IO **
    uv.fs_open(file_path, "w+", 438, function(err, fd)
        assert(not err, err)
        uv.fs_write(fd, data, nil, function(err_o, _)
            assert(not err_o, err_o)
            uv.fs_close(fd, function(err_c)
                assert(not err_c, err_c)
                print("finished:", file_path)
            end)
        end)
    end)
end

local function dl_url(url)
    local content, _, _, _ = http.request(url)
    write_file("foo.txt", content)
end

-- adding task to copas' loop
for _, url in ipairs(urls) do
    copas.addthread(dl_url, url)
end

main_loop()
```